# Как сделать копию гугл таблицы но чтобы у каждого юзера она была разной при вводе почты на gspread?

Tags: python

Я хочу сделать телеграмм бота который будет учитывать финансы. Использую язык Python и библиотеку gspread, aiogram. Основная задача, это вписывать расходы и доходы и чтобы они записывались в гугл таблицу.

Я создаю таблицу и начинаю прописывать свой код

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import time
import settings

time = str(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

scope = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
open_sheet = client.open(settings.SHEET_NAME)


def copy_sheet():
    copy_sheet = client.copy(open_sheet.id, title='Учет Финансов')
    return copy_sheet
```

Это питон файл от гугл таблицы, затем я импортирую ее в основной файл с ботом.

```
import spreadsheet as sp
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import time

API_TOKEN = Здесь токен бота

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%s" % + здесь надо вставить ссылку на таблицу

regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Введите вашу почту')


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def email(message: types.Message):
    sp.copy_sheet()
    copy_sheet.permission(email, perm_type='user, role='writer')
    await message.answer('Создаю гугл таблицу...')
    time.sleep(2)
    await message.answer('Таблица создана: ' + spreadsheet_url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Все создается и присылается ссылка, но есть одно но, каждый раз когда новый юзер вводит свою почту он получает тот же самый url, то есть копия таблицы создается один раз. **Как сделать так что бы он был другим для новых юзеров ?*** Буду рад любой помощи.